# Converting Non-linear Programming Problem from Maximization to Minimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have a non-linear maximization problem and I want to convert it to be a minimization problem, can I do so by multiplying it by a negative sign, or is that wrong; and if that is wrong what should I do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since I answered your question.... would you consider selecting it as the answer by selecting the check mark.  And welcome to SE Mathematics!

Answer (score 3):

Yes
$$f:X \to \mathbb{F}$$

$$\max_{x \in X} f(x) = -\min_{x \in X} f(x)$$

Consider for example, the non-linear maximization problem

$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}} -x^2 $$

this is equivalent to minimizing $x^2($in the sense that the minimizer for this is $x=0$ and your original function is maximized when $x=0)$

Comment: In fact, that it is nonlinear has nothing to do with this answer.